# Need help to find with dictionary objects in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, min

I have a dictionary object say:

```
d = {
    '25478329': ['17647430', '376088951', '32416061', '43096205'],
    '43096205': '17647430',
    '376088951': ['17647430', '25478329', '32416061'],
    '32416061': ['17647430', '25478329']
}
```

I need help finding the key with maximum numbers of data.
by data here I mean the string values inside the list.

Comment: Do you mean the key whose value is the largest list of strings?

Comment: ... and is one of your values really a string rather than a list of strings?

Comment: yes, the key whose value is the largest list of strings. and yes the values could be a string or list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could be clearer, but if what you want is what I suggested in the comments, this will work:

```
def keyfunc(item):
    key, value = item
    if isinstance(key, str):
        return 1
    else:
        return len(key)

max(d.items(), key=keyfunc)[0]
```

Here, we define a key function that takes a key/value 2-tuple as returned by [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and:

- if the value is a string, returns 1.
- otherwise, returns the length of the list of strings.

That key function is then used with the builtin [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function to return the item with the largest number of strings, and finally we use `[0]` to get the key from that item.

Comment: and If i have to find the string that has highest number of occurrence in the values of each key?

Comment: That's a different question ... go ahead and ask it (in a new question, not by editing this one) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to return the key that has the maximum numbers of data.

A pretty functional solution:

```
max_key = max(
    d.items(),
    key=lambda (_, values): len(values) if type(values) == list else 1
)[0]
```

Comment: Right, now checks if `values` is a list. If it's not, then assumes length 1.